# Why can't I use Cross Entropy Loss for multilabel?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I'm in the process of finetuning a BERT model to the long answer task in the Natural Questions dataset. I'm training the model just like a SQuAD model (predicting start and end tokens).

I use Huggingface and PyTorch.

So the targets and labels have a shape/size of ***[batch, 2]***. My problem is that I can't input "multi-targets" which I think is refering to the fact that the last shape is ***2***.

> RuntimeError: multi-target not supported at /pytorch/aten/src/THCUNN/generic/ClassNLLCriterion.cu:18

Should I choose another loss function or is there another way to bypass this problem?

This code I'm using:

```
def loss_fn(preds, targets):
    return nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(preds,labels)
```

```
class DecoderModel(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, model_args, encoder_config, loss_fn):
        super(DecoderModel, self).__init__()
        # ...

    def forward(self, pooled_output, labels):   
        pooled_output = self.dropout(pooled_output)
        logits = self.linear(pooled_output)

        start_logits, end_logits = logits.split(1, dim = -1)
        start_logit = torch.squeeze(start_logits, axis=-1)
        end_logit = torch.squeeze(end_logits, axis=-1)

        # Concatenate into a "label"
        preds = torch.cat((start_logits, end_logits), -1)

        # Calculate loss
        loss = self.loss_fn(
            preds = preds, 
            labels = labels)

        return loss, preds
```

The targets properties are:
***torch.int64*** & ***[3,2]***

The predictions properties are:
***torch.float32*** & ***[3,2]***

## SOLVED - this is my solution

```
def loss_fn(preds:list, labels):
    start_token_labels, end_token_labels = labels.split(1, dim = -1)
    start_token_labels = start_token_labels.squeeze(-1)
    end_token_labels = end_token_labels.squeeze(-1)

    print('*'*50)
    print(preds[0].shape) # preds [0] and [1] has the same shape and dtype
    print(preds[0].dtype) # preds [0] and [1] has the same shape and dtype
    print(start_token_labels.shape) # labels [0] and [1] has the same shape and dtype
    print(start_token_labels.dtype) # labels [0] and [1] has the same shape and dtype

    start_loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(preds[0], start_token_labels)
    end_loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(preds[1], end_token_labels)

    avg_loss = (start_loss + end_loss) / 2
    return avg_loss
```

Basically I'm splitting the logits (just not concatinating them) and the labels. I then do Cross Entropy loss on both of them and at last taking the average loss between the two. Hope this gives you an idea to solve your own problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not give 1-hot vectors to `CrossEntropyLoss`, rather the labels directly

> Target: (N) where each value is 0≤targets[i]≤C−1 , or (N, d_1, d_2, ..., d_K) with K≥1 in the case of K-dimensional loss.

You can reproduce  your error looking at the docs:

```py
>>> loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
>>> input = torch.randn(3, 5, requires_grad=True)
>>> target = torch.empty(3, dtype=torch.long).random_(5)
>>> output = loss(input, target)
>>> output.backward()
```

but if you change `target` to `target = torch.empty((3, 5), dtype=torch.long).random_(5)` then you get  the error:

> RuntimeError: 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported

Use `nn.BCELoss` with logits as inputs instead, see this example: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/multi-label-classification-in-pytorch/905/41

```
>>> nn.BCELoss()(torch.softmax(input, axis=1), torch.softmax(target.float(), axis=1))
>>> tensor(0.6376, grad_fn=<BinaryCrossEntropyBackward>)
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped! I ended up doing something similar, splitting the logits up into to pieces with the shape [3,1] and then doing CE loss on the two logits and then taking the average loss.